# Masking and shifting

Tags: c++, c

Should we first shift the value then mask or the other way? And what is the risk in first masking before shifting?

1. `((loc_Task_value_avg >> 8) & 0x00FF)`
   OR
2. `((loc_Task_value_avg & 0xFF00) >> 8)`

Comment: Did you **try** this?

Comment: It depends if you want to mask the shifted `loc_Task_value_avg` or if you want to shift the masked `loc_Task_value_avg`, you should do it the way you are supposed to do it, the risk is that they are not the same thing so the results will differ.

Comment: When you edit your question so that it becomes a completely new question, you should write it clearly instead of just editing the old question.

Comment: Assuming that your goal is to get bits[15..8] of the orginal value into a new variable on bit position [7..0] and at the same time ensuring that all other bits of the new variable are zero, you should always use the first style. The reason is that it will work correctly for any integer type while the second will fail for a 16 bit signed integer.

Answer (score 3):

Try working through these kind of examples with real numbers. In this case, you'll find they do not result in the same output.

We'll use two examples.

First, suppose loc_Task_value_avg is equal to 0x1234

```
((loc_Task_value_avg >> 8) & 0x00FF)
((0x1234 >> 8 ) & 0x00FF)
(0x0012 & 0x00FF)
0x0012
```

vs

```
((loc_Task_value_avg & 0xFF00) >> 8)
((0x1234 & 0xFF00) >> 8)
(0x0012 >> 8)
0x0012
```

The danger comes when we are using signed values. Let's use 0xFEDC.

```
((loc_Task_value_avg >> 8) & 0x00FF)
((0xFEDC >> 8 ) & 0x00FF)
(0xFFFE & 0x00FF)
0x00FE
```

vs

```
((loc_Task_value_avg & 0xFF00) >> 8)
((0xFEDC & 0xFF00) >> 8)
(0xFE00 >> 8)
0xFFFE
```

The reason we get two separate outputs is because when dealing with signed values (Two's complement), shifting from the highest to lowest order value may result in the sign bit being extended. Whether this happens depends on whether the instructions by the compiler use signed or unsigned shift.

Comment: Switched from 0xABCD to 0x1234 to avoid signing issues. The result may be different depending on whether the data is signed (positive vs negative), how data is signed, and which cpu instructions are used (e.g. signed vs unsigned shift). I don't want to add this above because it will overly complicate the answer but it is necessary to comment on this. :)

Comment: The question was changed, so I changed the answer to reflect the new question. I think the new question better reflects what the original asker's intentions are.

Comment: maybe you should mentioned that the signed problem is only present in case of a 16 bit signed variable, i.e. `short int` (on most systems). If the variable is a signed int with more than 16 bits, the two lines of code are the same.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of the value you are shifting, the number of bits in the mask and whether the underlying value is signed or unsigned.

A shift-right is a divide by 2. On a signed value this means the sign bit will be preserved (because the underlying representation is most likely twos compliment). If your shift is large enough to shift copied sign bits into the masked result, it will make a difference.

If the underlying value is unsigned, it doesn't matter whether you shift then mask or mask then shift.

Answer (score 1):

Each case would do different things.

Take the case with bits `1101`.

If I mask the second bit (the zero) and then shift it one, then I would have the value `0`.

On the other hand, if I shift the bits by one and then mask the second bit, I would have the value `1`.

It is important to clearly identify what exactly you are intending to do and then go about from there.